# Using vue.js and Auth0 how can i skip the login page if the user's already authenticated?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js, auth0

**DESCRIPTION**

I have a pretty standard `SPA` built with `vue.js` where I'm using `Auth0` to handle the authentication  part by following the [official](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs#display-the-user-s-profile) example. The app flow is as follows:

`Register in the Initial.vue via Auth0 lock` -> `Callback is called` -> `User's redirected to /home`

Everything in the above flow works fine but here's the problem:

**PROBLEM**

Once the user's registered and in the `/home` I want him to be able to access all the other routes (e.g. `/doctors`) if authenticated and if not he should be prompter to login again. According to the above link this is handled in the `router.beforeEach` function.

*My problem* appears when accessing the `/` login page (`Initialvue`). When the user's already registered and trying to access that route I want him to get redirected to the `/home` and skip the `login` page. I've tried implementing this with a `beforeEnter` route but `auth.isAuthenticated` fails due to the `tokenExpiry` being null (even-though user's authenticated!

**CODE**

My `AuthService.js`:

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import EventEmitter from 'events';
import authConfig from '../config/auth_config.json';

const webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  domain: authConfig.domain,
  redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
  clientID: authConfig.clientId,
  responseType: 'id_token',
  scope: 'openid profile email'
});

const localStorageKey = 'loggedIn';
const loginEvent = 'loginEvent';

class AuthService extends EventEmitter {
  idToken = null;
  profile = null;
  tokenExpiry = null;

  // Starts the user login flow
  login(customState) {
    webAuth.authorize({
      appState: customState
    });
  }

  // Handles the callback request from Auth0
  handleAuthentication() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      webAuth.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          this.localLogin(authResult);
          resolve(authResult.idToken);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  localLogin(authResult) {
    // console.log(authResult); TODO-me: Handle this
    this.idToken = authResult.idToken;
    this.profile = authResult.idTokenPayload;

    // Convert the JWT expiry time from seconds to milliseconds
    this.tokenExpiry = new Date(this.profile.exp * 1000);

    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, 'true');

    this.emit(loginEvent, {
      loggedIn: true,
      profile: authResult.idTokenPayload,
      state: authResult.appState || {}
    });
  }

  renewTokens() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) !== "true") {
        return reject("Not logged in");
      }``;

      webAuth.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          this.localLogin(authResult);
          resolve(authResult);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  logOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem(localStorageKey);

    this.idToken = null;
    this.tokenExpiry = null;
    this.profile = null;

    webAuth.logout({
      returnTo: window.location.origin
    });

    this.emit(loginEvent, { loggedIn: false });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
     console.log('In tokenExp is:');
     console.log(this.tokenExpiry); //THIS returns null when /home -> /
    return (
      Date.now() < this.tokenExpiry &&
      localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) === 'true'
    );
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

My `Initial.vue`:

```
<template>
    <v-container
        app
        fluid
    >
        <v-parallax
            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg"
            height="1000"
        >
            <v-layout
                row
                wrap
            >
                <!-- LOGIN-->

                    <v-toolbar
                        flat
                        light
                        dense
                        color="transparent"
                    >
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-toolbar-items>
                            <v-btn
                                medium
                                color="lime lighten-2"
                                @click="login"
                                class="font-weight-bold title text-uppercase"
                            >
                                Login
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-toolbar-items>
                    </v-toolbar>
            <v-layout
                align-center
                column
            >
                <h1 class="display-2 font-weight-thin mb-3 text-uppercase lime--text lighten-2" >Pulse</h1>
                <h4 class="subheading">A digital intelligent insurance built for you!</h4>
            </v-layout>

            </v-layout>
        </v-parallax>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import VContainer from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VContainer";
    import VFlex from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VFlex";
    import VLayout from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VLayout";
    import VBtn from "vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn";
    import VToolbar from "vuetify/lib/components/VToolbar/VToolbar";
    import VParallax from "vuetify/lib/components/VParallax/VParallax";

    export default {
        name: "Initial",
        components: {
            VContainer,
            VLayout,
            VFlex,
            VBtn,
            VToolbar,
            VParallax
        },
        data() {
            return {
            isAuthenticated: false
            };
        },
        async created() {
            try {
                await this.$auth.renewTokens();
            } catch (e) {
            // console.log(e);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
                this.$auth.login();
        },
            // logout() {
            //     this.$auth.logOut();
            // },
            handleLoginEvent(data) {
                this.isAuthenticated = data.loggedIn;
                this.profile = data.profile;
            }
        }


    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My `Callback.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      methods: {
        handleLoginEvent(data) {
            console.log('State.target is:');
            console.log(data.state.target);
          //If user has just signed up redirect to complete-signup form
          if ((data.profile['<AUTH_DOMAIN>'].justSignedUp) && (data.state.target===undefined)){
              // this.$router.push(data.state.target || "/complete-signup");
              this.$router.push('/complete-signup');
              }else {
                  // this.$router.push('/home');
                  this.$router.push(data.state.target);
              }
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.$auth.handleAuthentication();
      }
    }

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My `router.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import auth from '../auth/AuthService';

import Callback from '../components/Callback';

Vue.use(Router)

// export default new Router({
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        // {
        //     path: '/',
        //     name: 'login',
        //     component: () => import('@/views/Login')
        // },
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'initial',
            component: () => import('@/views/Initial'),
            // meta: {isAuth: true},
            beforeEnter: ((to, from, next) => {
                // if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isAuth)) {
                     console.log(auth.isAuthenticated()); //THIS is false for the above scenario
                    if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                        next({
                            path: '/home',
                            query: {redirect: to.fullPath}
                        })
                    } else {
                        next()
                    }
                // }
            })

        },
        {
            path: '/callback',
            name: 'callback',
            component: Callback
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('@/views/Home')
        },
        {
            path: '/doctors',
            name: 'doctors',
            component: () => import('@/views/Doctors')
        },
        {
            path: '/complete-signup',
            name: 'complete-signup',
            component: () => import('@/views/CompleteSignup')
        },

    ]
});

// Add a `beforeEach` handler to each route
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.path === "/" || to.path === "/callback" || auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  // Specify the current path as the customState parameter, meaning it
  // will be returned to the application after auth
    console.log('OUT beforeach if');
  auth.login({ target: to.path });
});
```

The 'CompleteSignup`is my signup form after registering where the user's is filling out a form and then posting it via`axios`and then redirected to`/home`:

```
//Form data before
methods: {
this.$store.dispatch(REGISTER,registerFormData)
          .then(() => this.$router.push('/home'));
}
```

I'm also using `vuetify` and my main `App.vue` component is:

```
<template>

    <v-app
        style= "background: #E0EAFC;  /* fallback for old browsers */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #CFDEF3, #E0EAFC);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #CFDEF3, #E0EAFC); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        "
    >  
      <v-content>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
</template> 


<script>   
  export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {

      }

  };


</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you checked the `authResult` in `localLogin` and verified that `tokenExpiry` is set correctly in the first place?

Comment: Yes. After registration I'm able to navigate in the app and I can also see in console that tokenExpiry has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem lies in the fact that the `this.tokenExpiry`, `this.idToken`, `this.profile` values are being assigned a value within the `callback` view which comes *after* the `login` one *and in addition to that* these values are tied to the specific Vue prototype instance that I'd defined in a `mixin`. So when navigating back to the initial page `this` is undefined since it's not associated to a specific Vue instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the problem by making the default behaviour the one where your user is logged in and then protect the respective routes with the route guard.

1) point your `/` to `/home`
2) create separate route for login/"intial"
3) use the `beforeEach` hook to ensure a user is authenticated and if not redirect him to your `Initial.vue` (or trigger `auth.login()` directly)

```
...
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'home'
  },
  {
    path: '/initial',
    ...
  ...
}
...
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.name == 'callback' || auth.isAuthenticated()) { 
    next()
  } else { // trigger auth0 login or redirect to your Initial.vue
    auth.login()
    // next({ path: '/initial' })
  }
})
```

Comment: Agreed; that would be a workaround. I will try it out. By the way, further debugging shows that all the `this` values (e.g. `idToken`, `profile`, `tokenExpiry`) are null in that case. Which leads me to believe that the component is not rendered when I'm trying to access the `this` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had been in the same situation (with React) and I will try to explain how to solve it.

1. First, in Authentication, it is necessary to store the token on the client side (localStorage / cookie can be used)
2. You need a `SecureComponent`, this component will only check if the stored token exists
3. `FetchHandler` this component handles each`Protected Application`
   and will inspect the response code, and if it is 401 (for example) it will redirect a User to the Authentication Component. This step can be added to `SecureComponent` as an additional layer.